# What should I use instead of Bootstrap?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I run this code:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
bs = cross_validation.Bootstrap(9, random_state=0)
```

I get this deprecation warning:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\p33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:684: DeprecationWarning: Bootstrap will no longer be supported as a cross-validation method as of version 0.15 and will be removed in 0.17
  "will be removed in 0.17", DeprecationWarning)
```

What should I use instead of the bootstrap?

Comment: What are you using ``Bootstrap`` for? it does a very strange thing (as normal bootstrap can not be used for estimating the test error).

Answer (score 8):

From [the scikit-learn 0.15 release notes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#id6), under "API changes summary"

> - `cross_validation.Bootstrap` is deprecated. [`cross_validation.KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold) or [`cross_validation.ShuffleSplit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit) are recommended instead.

And from [the source code itself](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3fbccca3824e58f10ff48ed619ad5e07577bba3/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L681-L685):

```
# See, e.g., http://youtu.be/BzHz0J9a6k0?t=9m38s for a motivation
# behind this deprecation
warnings.warn("Bootstrap will no longer be supported as a " +
              "cross-validation method as of version 0.15 and " +
              "will be removed in 0.17", DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: I edited this answer to provide the lecture link.  However, I still don't think this addresses the "why" behind the OP.  Bootstrap is a nice way to deal with degrees of freedom concerns.  Moreover, using out-of-bootstrap data to validate is analogous to using cross-validation.

So, I also do not understand why Bootstrap was deprecated.  It does have a real and important use case, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `BaggingClassifier`:

```
bag = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=your_estimator, 
                        n_estimators=100,
                        max_samples=1.0,
                        bootstrap=True,
                        n_jobs=-1)
bag.fit(X, y)
recalls = []
for estimator, samples in zip(bag.estimators_, bag.estimators_samples_):
    # compute predictions on out-of-bag samples
    mask = ~samples
    y_pred = estimator.predict(X[mask])
    # compute some statistic
    recalls.append(recall(y[mask], y_pred))
# Do something with stats, e.g. find confidence interval
print(np.percentile(recalls, [2.5, 97.5]))
```

Comment: I have a question: why the randomly drawn samples are smaller than the original sample size? Theoretically, every bootstrapped sample size should be of the same size as the original, but with repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, and the solution I found (as of scikit-learn 0.24) was to use the resample utility.

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
```

This will generate 1 bootstrap step with each call, using the default parameters which sample with replacement.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html